# Switching JPanels in JFrame and back

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, layout-manager

I am switching on button click to new `JPanel` with the use of:

```
JPanel newP = new ProjectPage();
contentPane.revalidate(); 
setContentPane(newP);
```

Where `ProjectPage` is:

```
 public class ProjectPage extends JPanel
```

But how I create button in my new `ProjectPage` class that will take me back to my original panel?

My main screen class declared like so:

```
public class MainScreen extends JFrame
```

Comment: here which one is the container Panel? means-are u setting ProjectPage as contentPane? or ProjectPage was added to container?

Comment: for more clear answer put your sample code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [CardLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665156/calling-awt-frame-methods-from-subclass/5786005#5786005).

[image: Game view]  [image: High Scores view]

See [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for details.

As more general advice, do not extend `JPanel` or `JFrame`, but simply keep references to them & build them as needed for each use.  Part of this problem seems to be scope - the relevant panels are not 'visible' to the calling code.  Keeping references to them in the main class is an easy solution to that.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go back to the original JPanel, you have to keep a reference of it somewhere in your class by adding a field `private JPanel oldPanel;`

When you create your new panel, get the old Panel and save it in that field like:

```
oldPanel = getContentPane();
JPanel newP = new ProjectPage();
contentPane.revalidate(); 
setContentPane(newP);
```

and when you want to go back to your original panel, you do:

```
setContentPane(oldPanel);
```